# how to pass object of a class created inside client to server?

Tags: c++, sockets, object

I have a client and a server class in which i am sending message from client to server by making use of TCP sockets.

I have a class created in client.cpp named as Employee consisting of variables such as :

```
           int emp_id;
           char *emp_name;
           float emp_weight;
```

My question is as follows:

1) How to send object of the employee class from client side to the server i.e how will i pass  employee_object shown as follows to server:

```
    employee_object.emp_id=10;
    employee_object *emp_name=new char[30];
    employee_object.emp_weight=50.2;
```

Any help will be of great help.I am doing this to make my self clear how to pass different objects of classes from client to server.

Answer (score 1):

You have two main options: directly write the struct or class to the socket, or "serialize" it.

If you do a direct write, it's quite simple, but it requires you take care that your client and server have the same "width" (32 or 64 bit) and "endianness" (little or big).  If you're dealing with regular Intel or AMD desktop or server machines only, this isn't much of an issue.

If you want to "serialize," the sky is the limit.  Look up Protocol Buffers, Cap'n'Proto, JSON, etc.  There are tons of libraries for this, but Stack Overflow is not the site to figure out which one you should use--you'll have to do some research.  Some key considerations are whether the format is human-readable (like JSON) and whether it is fast (like Cap'n'Proto, or the direct method mentioned previously).